# PHP Framework / Lib / Cms that will help me create a strong backend with permissions

Tags: php, drupal, orm, frameworks

I am drupal user normally but we just landed a fairly big project that sort of feels as if it would be better made outside of drupal, because of flexibility and performance and all of that.

Basically the only advantage in drupal is 2 or 3 things, the permissions system is in place, brilliant we would not have to create this.

Two, views is simply awesome, we don't have to spend all of our lives writing queries
Three, well generally a lot of stuff is "configurable", you write less code but perhaps at the expense of performance or flexibility.

So now to my question, is there any Framework or lib or CMS in PHP that is a little bit more lightweight than drupal, has a little bit more flexibility even though you'd have to do more stuff from scratch but maybe not "ALL" of it, if the permsisions part would be included and only that I am a happy guy.

Another awesome thing would be if this framework/lib/cms had some sort of permission based mapping between stored procedures in MySQL and the group/role of the user in the backend, that way I could easily tell the backend Group/Role X will have permission to execute [Insert stored procedure list here] , etc... or if it had ORM/ODM included that'd be nice as well.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: It might help if you can be more specific about "a little bit more lightweight" and "a little bit more flexibility". Where do you find that Drupal is too heavy and lacking flexibility?

Comment: You can use views to write queries and do your scaffolding or prototyping. Then when you're happy, you can use the views query in your custom code (cut and paste it). My point is: You have more choice than views or hand written queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me that you never really have used Drupal, not as a developer in any regard. Drupal is a CMS, but it's also a CMF. That is, it a framework to make your life as a developer very easy.

It's also extremely flexible, probably the most flexible CMS there is of it's size. Its flexibility can primarily be seen two places.

**Hooks**
This is a system within Drupal, that allow you to change what drupal should do when a thing happen. Like a user logging in, a form being created, a page being displayed, a node being deleted. You can react to almost anything and tweak it to do exactly what you want.

**The theme system**
Through the theme system you can alter how Drupal outputs any markup. There a many functions and templates defined in Drupal, that you can override and have Drup use your own to create the markup you want.

**Performance**
In regard to performance, I can say I know of sites with more than 100 million visits each month. So you can really make high performance sites with Drupal.

I think the things you find lacking in Drupal, is more a testament of a lack of knowledge on your part than the lack of Drupal. Drupal already has what you need, you only need to learn how to take advantedge of what's in Drupal already.

The things you find lacking